# How to get a specific account from web3 with version 1.2.x?

Tags: npm, ethereum, web3js, truffle, ganache

In an old version of web3 `web3.eth.accounts[0]` returns a sepcific account. I used it as a parameter for the vote function like this:

```
app.vote(1, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0]})
```

Since version **1.2.x** web3 uses `web3.eth.getAccounts()` to return a list of accounts the node controls.

How can I get a specific account like I did before with this web3 version?

Answer (score -1):

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount;
> undefined

// set the default account
web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe';
```